# SQL Query: How to select multiple instances of a single item without collapsing into a group?

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

I'm trying to do with following with an SQL query in Impala.  I've got a single data table that has (among other things) two columns with values that intersect multiple times.  For example, let's say we have a table with two columns for related names and phone numbers:

`Names        Phone Numbers
John Smith   (123) 456-7890
Rob Johnson  (123) 456-7890
Greg Jackson (123) 456-7890
Tom Green    (123) 456-7890
Jack Mathis  (123) 456-7890
John Smith   (234) 567-8901
Rob Johnson  (234) 567-8901
Joe Wolf     (234) 567-8901
Mike Thomas  (234) 567-8901
Jim Moore    (234) 567-8901
John Smith   (345) 678-9012
Rob Johnson  (345) 678-9012
Toby Ellis   (345) 678-9012
Sam Wharton  (345) 678-9012
Bob Thompson (345) 678-9012
John Smith   (456) 789-0123
Rob Johnson  (456) 789-0123
Kelly Howe   (456) 789-0123
Hank Rehms   (456) 789-0123
Jim Fellows  (456) 789-0123`

What I need to get from this table is a selection of each item from the Name column that has multiple entries from the Phone Numbers column associated with it, like this:

`Names      Phone Numbers
John Smith  (123) 456-7890
John Smith  (234) 567-8901
John Smith  (345) 678-9012
John Smith  (456) 789-0123
Rob Johnson (123) 456-7890
Rob Johnson (234) 567-8901
Rob Johnson (345) 678-9012
Rob Johnson (456) 789-0123`

This is the query I've got so far, but it's not quite giving me the results I'm looking for:

```
SELECT a.name, a.phone_number, b.phone_number, b.count1

FROM databasename a

INNER JOIN (

  SELECT phone_number, COUNT(phone_number) as count1

  FROM databasename

  GROUP BY phone_number

  ) b

ON a.phone_number = b.phone_number;
```

Any ideas on how to improve my query to get the results I'm looking for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with your query...

This generates a subset by name of users having more than 1 phone number it then joins back to the entire set based on name returning all phone numbers for users having more than 1 phone number.  however if a user has the same phone number listed more than once it would get returned.  to eliminate those if needed, add distinct to the count in the inline view.

```
SELECT a.name, a.phone_number
FROM databasename a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT name, COUNT(phone_number) as count1
  FROM databasename
  GROUP BY name
  having  COUNT(phone_number) > 1
  ) b
on a.name = b.name
Order by a.name, a.phone_Number
```

Comment: This is really great.  Thanks for the help!  I tried running this just now with the DISTINCT operator, and added a date line as well.  It's outputting results where we have one name with multiple phone numbers, but I'm also getting lines in the output where there's a single name and single phone number, but with a count higher than 1.  Here's my code in the next comment:

Comment: `SELECT a.date, a.name, a.phone_number
    FROM databasename a
    INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT phone_number) as count1
    FROM databasename
    GROUP BY name
    having count1 > 1
    ) b
    ON a.name = b.name
    WHERE a.date = '20150810'
    Order by a.name, a.phoneNumber;`

Comment: I updated my query seems to be working... you'd just have to add the where clause back in, as my sample table didn't have "dates"  now, the issue may be that a.date only has ONE value.  Updating your question to include date component and sample data may help me understand your situation better.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use exists:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where exists (select 1 from tablename t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.phonenumber <> t.phonenumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM my_table x 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.name = x.name 
            AND y.phone <> x.phone;
```